# Is using for loops faster than saving things in a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, vector, time

Sorry for the bad title, but I can actually not think of a better one (open to suggestions).

I got a big grid (1000*1000*1000).

```
for (int k = 0; k<dims.nz; k++);
{
 for (int i = 0; i < dims.nx; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < dims.ny; j++)
    {
        if (inputLabel->evalReg(i, j, 0) == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + anotherField->evalReg(i, j, 0);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I go through all grid points to find which grid points have the value 0 in my labelfield and sum up the corresponding values of another field.

After this I want to set all the points that I detected above to a certain value.

Would it be faster to do basically do the same for loop again (while this time setting values instead of reading them), or should I write all the positions that I got into a separate vector (which would have to change size in ever step of the loop in which we detect something) and simply build a for loop like

```
for(int p=0; p<size_vec_1,p++)
  {
    anotherField->set(vec_1[p],vec_2[p],vec_3[p], random value);
   }
```

The point is that I do not know how much of the grid will be affected by my routien due to different data. Might be half of the data or something completly different. Can I do a genereal estimation of the speed of the methods or is it soley depending on the distribution of my values ?

Comment: Chances are you could use ready-made library algorithms instead of loops.

Comment: You will most likely not get a definite answer here. It depends on many things like the operating system, size of the cache, speed of memory access… So, on some computers, one option may be faster, while on others, the other one is. You will only get a reasonable result by testing with different data on different machines.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @Caleth: that rant is for programmers who don't want to become better.

Comment: @geza I disagree with your definition of better. How long will it take for you to micro-optimise 1000 lines of code? 1 million? 1 billion?

Comment: @geza I disagree too. How can you become better without learning how to actually (a) measure your code, (b) compare different approaches, and (c) think about tradeoffs and optimal approaches across your common scenarios? Does instead simply posting "which of these two snippets is faster" on the internet really make you better? The article is not just good but crucial... and it's certainly not a "rant"!

Comment: @Caleth: when you have the choice, you should write the code already the better way. **When it takes nothing to do so**. Programmers should know which is the better way when deciding between solutions. Even if it is something like deciding between `++i` or `i++`. I'm not advocating changing already working code. And that rant is against this philosophy, that's why I disagree most part of it. Anyways, it is hard to discuss this issue in comments here, there's a lot more to say about it.

Comment: @geza Interestingly you have posted (and have had accepted) an answer that abides by these suggestions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Your (a)-(c) points are valid. About questions: you can get better by putting questions, and getting good answers with reasons. You can learn a lot of stuffs by this way. I'm not saying the whole rant is bad, but I disagree with its philosophy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: if the OP took Eric's advice, then OP didn't have asked this question. And maybe never got this solution. Sometimes problems are more complicated than "race your horses" (like this one).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sorry about calling it rant, I'm not a native speaker. Yes, it is not a rant. But I don't think that it is crucial or even just good for people who want to become better. Yes, it is good if someone wants to achieve a certain level, and just stay there.

Comment: I wasn't trying to imply this is an *objectively bad* question, at least in the sense that something resembling it *often comes up*. OP already has doubts of there necessarily existing a universal "faster".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In his introduction, Eric describes it as "my standard six-part rant"

Comment: I would ask whether `evalReg` is just inlined code reading an array, or whether it is doing anything more. If it takes some time, this may favor the vector approach, if it does not, it may well be better to always just rerun the loop.

Comment: @Caleth I'd say there's a difference between self-deprecating humour and actually calling someone else's article a rant :P

Comment: @geza: _"Sometimes problems are more complicated than 'race your horses' (like this one)."_ This is a rather simple problem and fits "race your horses" perfectly. However it is indeed pleasing that through this interaction the OP has now learnt that ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In my opinion, no, this problem is not solvable optimally with "race your horses". Look at my answer. The answer is not "race your horses". The answer is more complicated than that. And I'm not saying that my idea is the best either. Maybe someone can come up with something even better. But certainly not "race your horses" solution.

Comment: @geza The article is also more complicated than just those three words. The fundamental philosophy is adhered to by your answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sure :) Maybe I should write a point-by-point critique of that article, rather than arguing here. But the point is, if OP or me followed that article, then my answer wouldn't exist. Or maybe, citing that article is not suitable for this question, that article is not relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The point is that I do not know how much of the grid will be affected by my routien due to different data.

Here's a trick, which may work: sample `inputLabel` randomly, to make an approximation how many entries are 0. If a few, then go the "putting indices into a vector" way. If a lot, then go the "scan the array again" way.

It needs fine tuning for a specific computer, what should be the threshold between the two cases, how many samples to take (it should not be too large, as the approximation will take too much time, but should not be too small to have a good approximation), etc.

Bonus trick: take cache-line-aligned and cache-line-sized samples. This way the approximation will take the similar amount of time (because it is memory bound), but the approximation will be better.